# Can I still use Ubuntu after support period expired?

Tags: release-management

Can I still use it regardless of the customer support?

I just want to have Ubuntu for work and music, while my other OS is for gaming and general purposes.

Comment: Actually I also have 13.04 and I just don't want to upgrade because I customized it to my preference. I know from my experience of upgrading from 11.04 to above, I lost all my settings and had a hard time to get accustomed to it. To upgrade your packages you can use repos of LTS distros. The only downside of it is that you can not ask questions about 13.04 in askubuntu because moderators will simply close it.

Answer (score 3):

The end of support will also mean and end of (security) updates. It is not recommended to run a computer on the internet without keeping it up to date with security updates. Therefore, my answer would be: **yes** you **can** use it, but it is **not recommended**.

However, this should not be a problem. The function for updating the entire system to a new release of Ubuntu is very stable and reliable<sup>1</sup>, so when the new version comes out or when the support ends you can simply update. Once you hit a LTS (Long Term Support) release, it will have longer support period and thereby decrease the need for updating the system and will typically also have a updating route to the next LTS.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Unless you have heavily modified your system non-standard software and such, but from the sound of your question, that does not seem to be the case.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although if you really don't want to upgrade every 6 months then the best idea would probably be to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 when it comes out, then upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS when it comes out and then upgrade every 2 years from there.

You can still use the OS as long as you want without support, but there will be no more bug fixes, security fixes or support. If you haven't installed Ubuntu yet then I would recommend installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and sticking to the LTS releases every 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, course you can! But what's wrong with upgrading? Whenever you upgrade, Ubuntu will keep your settings, other systems, apps etc. You don't have to download the ISO again, it has a built-in updater. So I don't really see why you need to *not* upgrade. As @Ads20000 said, you could use LTS releases after you've got 14.04 - they are released every 2 years, but they support **security updates for 5 years**.